# Referencing an input textbox ID dynamically with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button with this name

```
GridView1__ctl2_AddButton0
```

I know how to get the middle part "ctl2"  (and whatever else it will be per row)  However, I want to use that to add a value to a textbox with lot of similar names

```
GridView1__ctl2_txtStormTimeOn
```

so while I know that I could do this

```
$('#GridView1__ctl2_txtStormTimeOn").val("whatever");   //works but I need to be DYNAMIC
```

Thus I want something like this

```
$('#GridView1__"+ myVal + "_txtStormTimeOn").val("whatever");
```

Comment: `$("#GridView1__"+ myVal + "_txtStormTimeOn").val("whatever")` you're saying it didn't work? Seems to be working just fine - http://jsfiddle.net/nuwwjcpk/ Probably minor syntax error on your code. Recheck

Comment: Per OP,  I had a ' single quote at the beginning, thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the single quote at the beginning before the #GridView1_ into a double quote

```
$("#GridView1__"+ myVal + "_txtStormTimeOn").val("whatever");
```